# Chaincode calling another chaincode (Hyperledger Fabric)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a network of 3 orgs and two channels.

**channelone**: org1, org2, chaincode- fabcar

**channeltwo**: org1, org3, chaincode- fabphone

I want to query chaincode- fabphone using fabcar.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke one chaincode from another by using stub.InvokeChaincode method-

```
response := stub.InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName, invokeArgs, channelName)
if response.Status != shim.OK {
  return nil
}

return response.Payload
```

for more details please refer- https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/-/blob/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L62:3

Answer (score 0):

If you write your chaincode in javascript or typescript you can use the following code:

```
const args = [functionName, ...]
const result = await ctx.stub.invokeChaincode(chaincodeName, args, channelName)

return result.payload.toString('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call fabphone from fabcar only by using org1 peer because the invokechaincode API works if the two calling each-other chaincodes are installed in the same peer

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible I think. You can only call chaincode functions inside the same channel. The function invokeChaincode uses the same transaction context as the original transaction.
Have a look into https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go

```
// InvokeChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Invoke` using the
// same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
// create a new transaction message.
func (stub *ChaincodeStub) InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName string, function string, 
args []string) ([]byte, error) {
return handler.handleInvokeChaincode(chaincodeName, function, args, stub.UUID)
}

// QueryChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Query` using the
// same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
// create a new transaction message.
func (stub *ChaincodeStub) QueryChaincode(chaincodeName string, function string, args 
[]string) ([]byte, error) {
return handler.handleQueryChaincode(chaincodeName, function, args, stub.UUID)
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct since one of the params for invoke is a channel ID